# How do you write this table filters into SQL SELECT Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to retrieve records from a database with multiple reports/tables.

Here is the filter from the report I am trying to convert into an SQL statement:

[image: Report filters]

And here is my SQL statement from that given report:

```
SELECT c.ClientId,
       c.State,
       c.BranchId,
       c.ClientName,
       c.AddressLine1,
       c.AddressLine2,
       c.AddressLine3,
       c.Suburb,
       c.City,
       c.CountryName,
       c.Postcode,
       c.Telephone,
       c.Mobile,
       c.Email,
       c.TradingAs,
       c.Contact,
       c.JobTitle,
       c.Classification,
       c.SalesTeamId,
       c.ServiceTeamId,
       c.AuthorisedRep1Id,
       c.ABN,
       p.PolicyDescription,
       p.PolicyNumber,
       t.ClassOfRiskname,
       t.InsurerId,
       t.ToDate
FROM Reports_Clients_Prospects c
     INNER JOIN Reports_Policies p ON c.ClientId = p.ClientId
     INNER JOIN Reports_Policy_Transactions t ON t.PolicyTransactionId = p.LatestTransactionId
WHERE c.ClientStatus = 'Current'
  AND c.Branch = 'ValueOne'
  AND c.AuthorisedRep1 != 'ValueTwo'
  AND p.RenewalType = 'Renewable'
  AND t.TransactionType != 'Quotation'
  AND t.ToDate >=: startDate
  AND t.ToDate <=: endDate;
```

The problem is that the filter from the report and the data from the sql are not the same. I was thinking the problem might be the sql using the 'inner join' statement? If it is, how would you write the sql select statement from the given filters above?

Comment: What is the `>=:` and `<=:` meant to be? That isn't valid T-SQL.

Comment: Usually you take your main table and LEFT JOIN the others to it.  When you INNER JOIN, you're only keeping records where both have matching data, and sometimes you don't want to do that.  Also, Larnu is correct.  Take out the semi-colons in those data variable calcs.

Comment: I'm very much not a fan of graphical report building tools. They miss **sooo much** of what SQL can do: different JOIN types, APPLY/lateral joins, CTEs, join to a subquery, conditional aggregation, PIVOT... and much more. A good developer will always be able to build the report better and faster in SQL, and even a good user of the report tool will still tend to make important performance and correctness mistakes using the tools.

Comment: @JohnnyBones LEFT JOIN won't help here. The additional conditional statements turn these into de facto INNER JOINs, even if they are defined as LEFT JOINs.

Comment: Renewable and Quotation could have specially interpretation.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no or?

Comment: Anyway, using SQLProfiler you can intercept the real statement executed by database server.

Comment: SQLProfiler is answer

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOINs are commutative operations. that's :

```
A INNER JOIN B <=> B INNER JOIN A
```

So there is no importance of the precendence of tables involved in the INNER JOINs...

The only part that is a little bit different from the report tool is the interval on the date that sould be write with the BETWEEN operator, like this :

```
AND t.ToDate BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
```

Some procedural languages use `:anystring` for variables...